# ScrollController how can I detect Scroll start, stop and scrolling?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using a `ScrollController` for a `SingleChildScrollView` widget where I want to detect *scroll start*, *scroll end/stop* and *still scrolling*.

How can I detect this?

I'm using `Listener`

```
    scrollController = ScrollController()
          ..addListener(() {
            scrollOffset = _scrollController.offset;
          });
```

Also try with `_scrollController.position.activity.velocity` but didn't help me.

Also there are

```
    _scrollController.position.didEndScroll();
    _scrollController.position.didStartScroll();
```

But how can I use it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From this link
https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac

Just Wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` to `NotificationListener` and update your code like ..

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
                  if (scrollNotification is ScrollStartNotification) {
                    _onStartScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
                  } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                    _onUpdateScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
                  } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
                    _onEndScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
                  }
                },
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                /// YOUR OWN CODE HERE
               )
)
```

And just declare method like

```
_onStartScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
    print("Scroll Start");
  }

  _onUpdateScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
    print("Scroll Update");
  }

  _onEndScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
    print("Scroll End");
  }
```

You will be notify by particular method.

Comment: This does not work right now due to an open issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44732

Answer (score 60):

No need for `NotificationListener`, we can use solely scroll controller for this.

First, register a post-frame callback by using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` to make sure that the scroll controller by that time has already associated with a scroll view. We will setup listener in that callback.

For listening to scrolling update we can use `scrollController.addListener`.

For listening to start and stop scrolling we can use `bgScrollCtrl.position.isScrollingNotifier.addListener`. You can check the code below:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      scrollCtrl.addListener(() { 
        print('scrolling');
      });
      scrollCtrl.position.isScrollingNotifier.addListener(() { 
        if(!scrollCtrl.position.isScrollingNotifier.value) {
          print('scroll is stopped');
        } else {
          print('scroll is started');
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Way better approach than the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is it appropriate to add notification in `addPostFrameCallback`?

Comment: @HensonFang I don't see any problem with that. I forgot to mention that we should call `addPostFrameCallback ` in stateful's `initState` callback to make sure scroll listener will be registered one-time only.

Comment: I think this answer must be accepted because it really answers the question

Answer (score 4):

```
_scrollController.position.pixels

if(_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent){
//scroll end
}
```

to use these, you should add a listener to your scrollview

Comment: Thanks but I wand to detect scroll start and stop. You any only detect end of the scroll. That my mistake let me update the question

Comment: you can use position.pixels for it

Comment: How can you give me expample

Comment: if position.pixels greater than minScrollExtent then scroll starts

Comment: This is what I want, Short and precise. Thanks for the sharing! :)

Comment: This is the end of the scrolling list. Not End scroll action

Answer (score 4):

NotificationListner not work for me because i animate scrollview. When i touch it **ScrollEndNotification** is called.

So to detect scrollview reach bottom or top. I added Listner to scrollcontroller.

```
  _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        debugPrint("reach the top");
      });
    }
    if (_scrollController.offset <= _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        debugPrint("reach the top");
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is the end of the scrolling list. Not End scroll action

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_scrollController.position.pixels` for getting scroll position and `addlistener` to be notified about changes

```
if(_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent){
//for scroll end
}

if(_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent){
//for scroll at top
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a package for this use case. [scroll_edge_listener](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_edge_listener)

You can detect either the start or the end of the scroll with a few configurations such as offset and debounce. Just wrap your scroll view with the `ScrollEdgeListener` and attach a listener.

```dart
ScrollEdgeListener(
  edge: ScrollEdge.end,
  edgeOffset: 400,
  continuous: false,
  debounce: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  dispatch: true,
  listener: () {
    debugPrint('listener called');
  },
  child: ListView(
    children: const [
      Placeholder(),
      Placeholder(),
      Placeholder(),
      Placeholder(),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

update 2023 :
to check scroll stop after scrolling

```
if(notification.direction == ScrollDirection.idle)
```