# Flutter. Nested scroll inside PageView

Tags: flutter, scroll, uipageviewcontroller, flutter-pageview

I have simple pages with `PageView` widget, and inside there is `ListView`. And where scrolling `PageView` will not work. The reason is simple. Because pointer event consumed by nested child.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setupController();

    return PageView(
      controller: controllerPage,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            controller: controller,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(AppDimens.bounds),
            itemCount: 15,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Container(
                height: 100,
                color: index %2 == 0 
                    ? Colors.amber : Colors.blueAccent,
              );
            },
          ),
        Container(color: Colors.green),
        Container(color: Colors.blue),
      ],
    );
  }
```

**My question is there any sane way to make it works together?** You might see vertical axis for the `PageView`, but exactly the same issue would appear by using horizontal axis of the `PageView` and horizontal `ListView`.

**What I have tried so far?** I have some workaround for it. Even it's not complicated, it's just feels not so good and clunky. By using `AbsorbPointer` and custom controllers for the scrolling.

```
  final controller = ScrollController();
  final controllerPage = PageController(keepPage: true);
  bool hasNestedScroll = true;

  void setupController() {
    controller.addListener(() {

      if (controller.offset + 5 > controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
          !controller.position.outOfRange) {
        /// Swap to Inactive, if it was not
        if (hasNestedScroll) {
          setState(() {
            hasNestedScroll = false;
          });
        }
      } else {
        /// Swap to Active, if it was not
        if (!hasNestedScroll) {
          setState(() {
            hasNestedScroll = true;
          });
        }
      }
    });

    controllerPage.addListener(() {
      if (controllerPage.page == 0) {
        setState(() {
          hasNestedScroll = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setupController();

    return PageView(
      controller: controllerPage,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: <Widget>[
        AbsorbPointer(
          absorbing: !hasNestedScroll,
          child: ListView.builder(
            controller: controller,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(AppDimens.bounds),
            itemCount: 15,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Container(
                height: 100,
                color: index %2 == 0
                    ? Colors.amber : Colors.blueAccent,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(color: Colors.green),
        Container(color: Colors.blue),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: So are you trying to scroll on the PageView and the ListView at the same time?

Comment: @AlaricJamesHartsock No, I'm trying to scroll `ListView`, whenever it's has space. Once the scroll of the ListView reached the end, I need to scroll `PageView`

Comment: @AlaricJamesHartsock Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry man, I'm beat. Maybe try looking into the API and see if you can manually relinquish scroll control from your listview to your pageview once it's all the way scrolled down. I hope you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I got stuck in a similar scenario recently and after some research and reading about how gestures work under the hood in flutter, I found a good enough working solution.
So I used **RawGestureDetector** which gives you a low level widget handling of gestures and disabled the scrolling for PageView and ListView by setting their `physics` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`. This meant scrolling these widgets using their respective controllers - `PageViewController` and `ScrollController`. Now according to position and state of ListView, an active controller of the two is chosen and dragged using the controller. The main class would look something like this.

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: NestedContainerWidget()));
  }
}

class NestedContainerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NestedContainerWidgetState createState() => _NestedContainerWidgetState();
}

class _NestedContainerWidgetState extends State<NestedContainerWidget> {
  PageController _pageController;
  ScrollController _listScrollController;
  ScrollController _activeScrollController;
  Drag _drag;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
    _listScrollController = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    _listScrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    if (_listScrollController.hasClients &&
        _listScrollController.position.context.storageContext != null) {
      final RenderBox renderBox =
          _listScrollController.position.context.storageContext.findRenderObject();
      if (renderBox.paintBounds
          .shift(renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero))
          .contains(details.globalPosition)) {
        _activeScrollController = _listScrollController;
        _drag = _activeScrollController.position.drag(details, _disposeDrag);
        return;
      }
    }
    _activeScrollController = _pageController;
    _drag = _pageController.position.drag(details, _disposeDrag);
  }

  void _handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    if (_activeScrollController == _listScrollController &&
        details.primaryDelta < 0 &&
        _activeScrollController.position.pixels ==
            _activeScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      _activeScrollController = _pageController;
      _drag?.cancel();
      _drag = _pageController.position.drag(
          DragStartDetails(
              globalPosition: details.globalPosition, localPosition: details.localPosition),
          _disposeDrag);
    }
    _drag?.update(details);
  }

  void _handleDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    _drag?.end(details);
  }

  void _handleDragCancel() {
    _drag?.cancel();
  }

  void _disposeDrag() {
    _drag = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawGestureDetector(
      gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
        VerticalDragGestureRecognizer:
            GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(), (VerticalDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
          instance
            ..onStart = _handleDragStart
            ..onUpdate = _handleDragUpdate
            ..onEnd = _handleDragEnd
            ..onCancel = _handleDragCancel;
        })
      },
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      child: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Center(child: Text('Page 1')),
          ListView(
            controller: _listScrollController,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: List.generate(
              20,
              (int index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Look at the logic in `_handleDragStart` and `_handleDragUpdate` which determines the controller that should be scrolled according to the state of the `ListView` widget and it's scrolling state.

I wrote a detailed article on this problem, you can check it here - https://medium.com/@Mak95/nested-scrolling-listview-inside-pageview-in-flutter-a57b7a6241b1

The solution can be improved, so inputs would be much welcome.

Comment: Always add tag to your questions so that it can be viewed by the right crowd.

Comment: Is there any way to have multiple nested list view children in page view ?

Answer (score 1):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56072729/12571630) to help me fix the same problem.

basically, you listen to the scrollable child for an `OverscrollNotification` using `NotificationListener` and scroll the parent using its controller.

code:

```dart
final pageCntrler = PageController();

_scrollDown() async {
  await pageCntrler.nextPage(
    duration: scrollDuration,
    curve: scrollCurve,
  );
}

_scrollUp() async {
  await pageCntrler.previousPage(
    duration: scrollDuration,
    curve: scrollCurve,
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return PageView(
    controller: pageCntrler,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: [
      NotificationListener(
        onNotification: (notification) {
          if (notification is OverscrollNotification) {
            if (notification.overscroll > 0) {
              _scrollDown();
            } else {
              _scrollUp();
            }
          }
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```