# Flutter Detect if user is scrolling

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, scrollcontroller

I am using [ClickableListWheelView](https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view) and I would like to add a notification to it, so I can check when the user starts/stops scrolling. For that I tried this inside `_ClickableListWheelScrollViewState`'s `init` :

Got it from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63675037/11968226

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  scrollCtrl.addListener(() { 
    print('scrolling');
  });
  scrollCtrl.position.isScrollingNotifier.addListener(() { 
    if(!scrollCtrl.position.isScrollingNotifier.value) {
      print('scroll is stopped');
    } else {
      print('scroll is started');
    }
  });
});
```

But this is only printing "scrolling" but never "stop/start".

**I do not want to wrap the view inside a `NotificationListener`**.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

If you, for some reason, are avoiding the very helpful widget `NotificationListener`, then you might find [this GestureDetector hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64457895/detect-if-scrollable-widget-is-scrolled-manually-or-programatically) useful

It's not perfect, but basically you wrap the scrollable widget you're using (`SingleChildScrollView`, `Wrap`, etc) in a `GestureDetector`, and use its `onTapDown` to assume the user has begun scrolling, and `onTapUp` to assume they've stopped scrolling, and it can work for most cases.

I haven't tested this code, but here's an example to give you insight:

```dart
ClickableListWheelScrollView(
  //...
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTapUp: () {
      print('scrolling has stopped');
    },
    onTapDown: () {
      print('scrolling has started');
    },
    child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
      //...
    ),
  ),
)
```